# Archaic Greek Letters in Math Papers

Tags: notation, math-history

Is there any precedent for using [archaic Greek letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archaic_Greek_alphabets#Digamma_.28Wau.29) like [koppa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koppa_(letter)) or [sampi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampi) in mathematical papers?

Comment: I've never seen them.  Can TeX support them?  Certainly \koppa or \sampi don't seem to work.  These days, I'd say that if the usual type setting codes can't support it then you probably shouldn't use it (personal opinion, clearly).

Comment: @lulu  There are a couple of posts on tex.se about how to get koppa. But yes, maybe you're right.

Comment: This does not really seem like a question about mathematics. Perhaps it could be on-topic at [hsm.se], but I'm not sure if it isn't too vague.

Comment: @Danu I don't understand.  How is it vague? And how is a question about symbols used by mathematicians not on topic for the notation tag?  Do you mean it's overly broad, in that its a question about the entire corpus of published mathematical research?  Id accept that.  But vague or off topic I don't understand.

Comment: Instead of "vague", I should probably have used "unspecific".